# no owner defined between classes - am I using a reserved keyword?

Tags: groovy, owner

I've changed my classes a few times trying to get this. I keep getting a no owner defined between classes. I've tried putting the owner on both sides of the relationship, but with no effect. Here's the pertinent portions of the classes. I also tried marking both with belongsTo for the other class, but it still didn't work.

```
class Person {

String serialNumber
String personName
String password

static hasMany = [accounts:ClientAccount]

class ClientAccount {

String accountId

static hasMany = [productOrders: ProductOrder, people: Person]
static belongsTo = [person:Person]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "owner" is, but your groovy certainly won't compile.  You need to "close" the class definitions of Person and ClientAccount with '}'.

```
class ProductOrder {
}

class ClientAccount {
    String accountId
    static hasMany = [productOrders: ProductOrder, people: Person]
    static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}

class Person {
    String serialNumber
    String personName
    String password

    static hasMany = [accounts:ClientAccount]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, these are copied and pasted. The classes are closed properly. I only copied the groovy stuff. The only other things in the classes are toString methods